# How to get the path of the current root_dir using FileContentsManager? (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I know that the module FileContentsManager has the root_dir, however, I don't know how to create an instance of this module in runtime and get the current root_dir. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a `FileContentsManager` is to `from traitlets.config import Config` and run `Config()`, but that will just contain the default values and will be useless to you. The below code assumes you've already run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to generate `jupyter_notebook_config.py` and have edited and uncommented the line containing `c.FileContentsManager.root_dir =`:

```
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_dir
from traitlets.config import Config
import os

c = Config()
file_path = os.path.join(jupyter_config_dir(), 'jupyter_notebook_config.py')
exec(open(file_path).read())
root_dir = c['FileContentsManager']['root_dir']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do that by

```
def load_jupyter_server_extension(nb_app):
web_app = nb_app.web_app
host_pattern = '.*$'
# here
print("test" + nb_app.notebook_dir)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything.